# Icon causes gap in View - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, vector-icons

I have a ListView that looks as such:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the dropdown arrow Icon creates a gap on the left side of each item just above the first bit of text. I want to avoid having this gap, current code:

```
<Item key={i+tk}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({prevIndex: this.state.activeIndex, activeIndex: i+tk,
                    messageJustClosed:  (this.state.prevIndex === i+tk  && !this.state.messageJustClosed)})} style={{flex: 1}}>
                <View>
                    <Icon  name= {this.getIconImage(i+tk)} size={30} color="black" style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}/>

                    <Text style = {styles.text}>{messageType[i].title}</Text>
                  <Text style = {styles.dateText}>{new Date(messageType[i].created).toString().substring(0,21)}</Text>
                  <Expand value={ ((this.state.activeIndex === i+tk) && !(this.state.prevIndex === i+tk) ) || ((this.state.activeIndex === i+tk && this.state.messageJustClosed)) }>
                    <Text style = {{color: 'black'}}>{messageType[i].message}</Text>
                  </Expand>
                </View>

                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Item>
```

I tried placing it inline with the  tag as such:

```
<Text style = {styles.text}>{messageType[i].title} <Icon  name= {this.getIconImage(i+tk)} size={30} color="black" style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}/> </Text>
```

This gets rid of the gap, but doesn't place it in the same place (to the right of the screen). I tried giving the Text tag a flex of 1 but that messed things up completely, is there a way I can get the Icon inline with the text and all the way to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<View>` that contains the icons and the cell content is rendering with the default `flexDirection: column`, so if you change to `flexDirection: row` you can accomplish what you're after.

Here's an example of how to compose your JSX:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{messageType[i].title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.dateText}>{new Date(messageType[i].created).toString().substring(0, 21)}</Text>
          <Expand
            value={
              (this.state.activeIndex === i + tk && !(this.state.prevIndex === i + tk)) ||
              (this.state.activeIndex === i + tk && this.state.messageJustClosed)
            }
          >
            <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>{messageType[i].message}</Text>
          </Expand>
        </View>
        <Icon name={this.getIconImage(i + tk)} size={30} color="black" />
      </View>
```